Simple query taking way too long
I have a simple query, using an indexed column, on a very small data set, returning 1 row, hitting Azure SQL Database - taking over 1/2 second. Another earlier execution of this query took 38ms.
Execution Plan (thank you J.D.)
The query:
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId]
FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[UserId] = @__id_0

There are 36 rows in the database. The UserId is a string that is a GUID. The ClaimType & ClaimValue are strings that are 1 to 35 characters long.
The UserId is indexed.

2 rows of data:
Id  ClaimType   ClaimValue  UserId
5   SysAdmin    *   e69fac60-ea9b-4f73-8c7b-4cb75ec9721a
6   Admin   Arapahoe    e69fac60-ea9b-4f73-8c7b-4cb75ec9721a

How do I figure out why the slow read (sometimes)?

maybe compare hashes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976164/comparing-large-number-of-big-string-text-in-sql-server-is-performance-better

@nbk Good idea. Before I go to that effort though, what if I defined that UserId column as 36 characters as it's always that size? This is from a MS library which has the size larger, but I can reduce it to 36. And is there any kind of optimization if it's set somehow to exactly 36 characters (never less either)?

If it's always a Guid then why not uniqueidentifier? Either way 36 rows should fit on a single page so whatever you do is pretty much immaterial. Something else is going on, possibly Azure auto-shutdown-on-idle or slow authentication.

Try to insert the result in #t: SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId]
into #t
FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[UserId] = 'e69fac60-ea9b-4f73-8c7b-4cb75ec9721a'; if it's execution takes 0 seconds then the problem is not your query but your network and the time you see is the time it takes to bring the result to dlient

@sepupic I got the error "There is already an object named '#t' in the database." What I ran as the query is "#t: SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId] into #t FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a] WHERE [a].[UserId] = 'e69fac60-ea9b-4f73-8c7b-4cb75ec9721a'" - is that correct (I could not find what the "#t:" means so I was blindly running this. TIA

As for performance between NCHAR(36), or NVARCHAR(36+) vs UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to store a GUID (that is always a GUID)... you might see some very small benefits to more efficient memory grants for queries based purely on how the engine estimates strings vs UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS, but it isn't going to affect you here, on a table that fits on a single page.

thank you everyone for your advice

@DavidThielen This error means that you executed my code at least twice, and the second time there is already table #t. you can add if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t before my code with select into to be sure there is no such a table.

The cost of this query is trivial.  So if it's sometimes slow, it's probably blocking.  Query Store would tell you
 <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="0" ElapsedTime="0" />

If it's slow because other sessions are modifying the table and it's blocked, you can read with SNAPSHOT isolation, or switch the database to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT mode.

I'll dive in to this (thank you). But I'm 99% certain nothing is writing to it. And the reads for this specific case should not be simultaneous. They can be with multiple users but this was a single user test.
